# Reverse Engineer SQLServer(2017) schema into Visio 2019 Pro

Tags: sql-server, microsoft-visio

Trying to get Visio 2019 (or 2016) Pro to Reverse Engineer the schema from a SQLServer 2017 DB.

I can reverse the tables without issue using the generic ODBC driver but the option to reverse views remains greyed out.

If I try to use the SQL Server options I get the message "The currently selected Visio driver is not compatible with the data source".

I installed the latest versions of the ODBC drivers but nothing worked.

Comment: There are a number of free ER diagram tools; perhaps one might work. https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-best-free-DB-schema-design-tool

Comment: Thanks - I'll look at them as alternatives. I'd really like to get Visio to work:
<ul>
1. because it's supposed to, 
2. we have the licenses, 
3. the refresh functionality is a useful check on changes

Answer (score 0):

According to the article "[Reverse engineer an existing database into a database model](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/reverse-engineer-an-existing-database-into-a-database-model-fb034862-acfc-45bc-88b2-f33d1e1f8614#ID0EAABAAA=Visio_2016-2019)", the Reverse Engineer Wizard isn't available in Visio Professional 2016/2019 or Visio Standard 2016/2019. In order to use the database modeling features, consider upgrading to Visio Online Plan 2.

Comment: Web page now says: This template is available in the Visio app for those with Visio Online Plan 2 or a Visio 2019 license.